# GLSL image projection

Tags: opengl, glsl, projection

I have implemented projecting an Image onto my 3D scene (in WorldWind) using shaders. The problem I have now is that the image is projected onto and through objects in my scene. How do I prevent my projection from going through blocking objects? I am just learning opengl and glsl. Is Shadow Mapping or Shadow Volumes the solution or is there some other simple solution?

Comment: Shadow mapping is your best bet, as that is literally a specialized application of texture projection. Shadow Volumes are more involved, requiring a lot more setup and some special conditions that are not always easy to achieve (e.g. models generally need to be closed surfaces). But since you are just beginning with OpenGL neither one is going to be easy :-\ You'll have to learn FBOs to implement shadow maps, so if you are still interested, I would begin there.

Comment: @Andon I implemented shadow mapping using an FBO/depth map. It seems to work well on the 3D models in my scene but not very well on the terrain where the light and terrain are close to parallel. It seems to suffer from projective aliasing. Any suggestions on  how to improve that? Would a different method better solve this issue?